# Agrupar resultados en MYSQL aplicando inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy intentando agrupar 3 tablas relacionadas este seria el codigo sql

```
SELECT *
FROM metadata_values mvalues
INNER JOIN metadata_descriptors mdes ON mdes.idDescriptor = mvalues.idDescriptor
INNER JOIN metadata_schemas mschema ON mschema.idSchema = mdes.idSchema
```

Me trae todos los resultados pero lo que busco es agruparlos.

Comment: a que llamas agruparlos?

Comment: con el `group by mvalues.idDescriptor` los ordenas por su llave primaria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Te resultado final para agruparlos en un JOIN puede ser asi**

```
SELECT *
FROM metadata_values mvalues
INNER JOIN metadata_descriptors mdes ON mdes.idDescriptor = mvalues.idDescriptor
INNER JOIN metadata_schemas mschema ON mschema.idSchema = mdes.idSchema
GROUP BY mvalues.names ASC;
```

> Simplemente al final de tu consulta, coloca la instrucción `GROUP
>   BY()` e indicas el nombre de la tabla y columna que deseas sea el
>   motivo de agrupación
>
> Como notas en el ejemplo que puse agrupare por el nombre de la tabla
>   que se llama mvalues, lo cual logrará que si existe mas de un registro
>   con el mismo nombre los agrupe, dicho sea de paso la sentencia en mención trabaja con las sentencias de agrupación; que son max, min, sum, avg, etc

**EJEMPLO**

Haciendo uso de una setencia con JOIN obtengo los datos de los usuarios y sus posts hechos; de este modo

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT users.nameUser, posts.namePost
    -> FROM users JOIN posts ON users.idUser = posts.user_id
    -> ;
```

**MI RESULTADO ES**

```
+----------+----------+
| nameUser | namePost |
+----------+----------+
| alfa     | PHP-7    |
| beta     | HTML-5   |
| beta     | MYSQL-8  |
| alfa     | aire     |
+----------+----------+
```

Haciendo uso de la sentencia GROUP BY y de la función de agregación count() ya solo obtendré los usuarios agrupados y el total de posts de cada uno

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT users.nameUser, posts.namePost, COUNT(posts.namePost)
    -> FROM users JOIN posts ON users.idUser = posts.user_id
    -> GROUP BY users.nameUser;
```

**este es mi resultado**

```
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| nameUser | namePost | COUNT(posts.namePost) |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| alfa     | PHP-7    |                     2 |
| beta     | HTML-5   |                     2 |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
```