# un fetch_array con while e if me duplica los resultados en un fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]   Tengo el siguiente problema, cuando intento imprimir el while, me duplica los resultados, tengo este mismo formato de pdf para otra consulta que solo consulta una tabla, y funciona muy bien, sin duplicar datos, pero al trabajar con otro pdf en el cual necesito emplear una consulta a dos tablas donde me tome informacion de una tabla para complementar la informacion de dicho pdf, lo raro es que me duplica los datos, y no me lo venia haciendo, includo al sustituir el while por un if, solamente me trae un registro de la base de datos. Quisiera saber de que manera pudiera resolver este tema. Tomando en cuenta que los encabezados, titulos; como nro orden, cliente, direccion, necesito tomarlos de la base de datos obviamente, y luego abajo muestro otros campos de esa misma fila que forma parte del encabezado del pdf. Eh intentado colocando varios while, reemplazando el primer if, y no logro obtener el resultado, porque al colocar un if en vez de while solo me trae un resultado. Les agradeceria una orientiacion. gracias

```
       ?php

      require '../fpdf/fpdf.php';
      require '../abrir_conexion_cliente.php';

      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      { require '../abrir_conexion_cliente.php';

       $identificacion=$_POST['identificacion'];
       $id_orden=$_POST['id_orden'];
       $acentos = $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");  
       $productos ="SELECT 
        e.empresa,a.serie,a.tarjeta,e.direccion,a.cable_hdmi,
        .cable_av,a.fuente,a.control_1,a.id_orden,
         a.identificacion,e.nombre_cliente,
  a.horario_rec,e.password_rec,e.id_recolector_2,a.estado,adicional 
   FROM 
  express e INNER JOIN autorizar a on 
  e.identificacion=a.identificacion
  WHERE a.id_orden = '$id_orden' and 
 a.identificacion='$identificacion'";
 $acentos = $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 $result = $conn->query($productos);
 if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0){

if($productos2= $result->fetch_array())
 {
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', array(100,75));
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,14);
$pdf->SetFillColor(134,203,236);
$pdf->Rect(0,0,280,16,'F');
$pdf->SetY(20);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',5);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->Write(-15,'COMPROBANTE DE RETIRO DE EQUIPO Y COMPONENTES');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',2.5);
$pdf->Ln(2);
$pdf->SetX(14);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->Write(-15,'IMPORTANTE Por consulta sobre el presente retiro  / ');

$pdf->SetTextColor(7,4,3);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Image('../img/logo.png', 1.5,0.1, 10);
$pdf->Image('../img/qr.png',61,1,11,10);
$pdf->SetY(15);
$pdf->Ln(0.5);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);
$pdf->Cell(-25,6,'',0,0,'C');


$pdf->Cell(100,7,$productos2['empresa'],0,0,'C');
$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.5);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(134,203,236);
$pdf->Line(0, $pdf->GetY() + 6, 140, $pdf->GetY() +6);
$pdf->SetY(34);
$pdf->Ln(-14);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',3);
$pdf->Cell(-53,4,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,6,'Remito Nro. Orden:',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-24,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(1,6,$productos2['id_orden'],0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-25,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln(2.3);
$pdf->Cell(-54.9,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,6,'Cliente Nro:',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-24.5,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(7,6,$productos2['identificacion'],0,0,'C');

$pdf->Ln(1.6);
$pdf->Cell(-48.3,2,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(86,7,'Direccion:',0,0,'C');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',3);
$pdf->SetX(-108);
$pdf->Cell(135,7,$productos2['direccion'],0,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln(2);
$pdf->Cell(-51.4,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',3);
$pdf->Cell(95.1,7,'Nombre Cliente:',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-37,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(34,7,$productos2['nombre_cliente'],0,0,'C');


$pdf->Ln(2);
$pdf->Cell(-7.2,7,'Fecha Recupero:',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-1.4,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(66,7,$productos2['horario_rec'],0,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln(2);
$pdf->Cell(-8.6,7,'Fecha Remito:',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-1,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(66,7,date('d/m/Y'),0,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln(2);
$pdf->Cell(-11.8,7,'Estado:',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(2.5,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(66,7,$productos2['estado'],0,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln(2);

$pdf->Cell(-13,7,'Otro:',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(3.5,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(66,7,$productos2['adicional'],0,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln(0);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.5);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(134,203,236);
$pdf->Line(0, $pdf->GetY() + 6, 140, $pdf->GetY() +6);

$pdf->SetY(74);

$pdf->Cell(6,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(80,7,$productos2['id_recolector_2'],0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(-94,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(66,7,$productos2['password_rec'],0,0,'C');

$pdf->Ln(2);
$pdf->Cell(-46.2,6,'',0,0,'C');



$pdf->SetY(47);
$pdf->Ln(-5);


$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.2);
$pdf->SetFillColor(240,240,240);
$pdf->SetTextColor(40,40,40);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(255,255,255);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',3);
$pdf->Cell(-8.5,6,'',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(13,4,'Serie',1,0,'C',1);

$pdf->Cell(13,4,'Tarjeta',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(14.5,4,'Cable HDMI',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(12,4,'Cable AV',1,0,'C',1);

$pdf->Cell(9,4,'Fuente',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(10,4,'Control',1,0,'C',1);

$pdf->Ln(2);



$pdf->SetY(42);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.2);
$pdf->SetFillColor(240,240,240);
$pdf->SetTextColor(40,40,40);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->Ln(4.2);








//Creamos las celdas para los titulo de cada columna y le asignamos un fondo gris y el tipo de letra






while($productos2= $result->fetch_array())
   {




$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',3);
$pdf->Cell(-8.4,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(11,3,$productos2['serie'],0,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(16,3,$productos2['tarjeta'],0,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(12,3,$productos2['cable_hdmi'],0,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(16,3,$productos2['cable_av'],0,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(3.5,3,$productos2['fuente'],0,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(12.8,3,$productos2['control_1'],0,0,'C',1);


$pdf->Ln(3.5);


   }


   }


    else {
    echo "<div class='container'><div class='alert alert- 
  info'>¡Consulta Incorrecta! ¡Intente nuevamente!</div></div>";
   }
   $pdf->Output();
    }




    ?>
```

Comment: Ejecuta la consulta en PhpMyAdmin, seguramente ahí también saldrán repetidos y solo necesitas agrupar, tal vez por serie.

Comment: si! me salen duplicados en mysql. Como los puedo agrupar?

Comment: Al final de la consulta agrega `GROUP BY a.serie` o la columna que se esté repitiendo y te recomiendo probar primero en PhpMyAdmin; cuando tengas los resultados esperados, entonces actualizas tu script.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Agrupar resultados en MYSQL aplicando inner join](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190478/agrupar-resultados-en-mysql-aplicando-inner-join)

Comment: me sirvio con el Group By a.serie. Muy bien.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias cambiar la sentencia `if($productos2= $result->fetch_array())` en:

`if($productos2= $result->fetch_assoc())` .

Las diferencias entre las funciones es fetch_array trae el array y el indice duplicado para que se pueda acceder por ejemplo como **$array[0]** y **$array['columna']**.
Mientras que assoc_array NO trae los indices, sólo los datos y el indice asociativo a la columna.

He tenido que consulta un poco en internet para estar seguro de las diferencias.
La fuente está en inglés:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361184/mysqli-fetch-assoc-vs-fetch-array

que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Tu sugerencia solo es en cuestión de rendimiento, pero no soluciona el problema.